# Burning LDL with bike rides

Tags: nutrition, bicycling

I am trying to burn off LDL cholesterol by trying to stay in the fat burning zone(i use a wahoo HR monitor to track my zones)

I have hypertension and i love cycling, i usually take whey protein post my rides (Like whey from my history at gym and the filling feeling of post workout diet)

I am wondering if taking whey post cycling might be taking me back to square one in terms of calorie burning equation. Should i be worried about it or its fine to keep taking whey with milk?

Answer (score -1):

Trick to lose fat by cycling is start a ride with empty stomach with a super light breakfast/snack. Then ride must be steady for long period as much as possible like 5 to 6 hours without stopping for any food/lunch. Drinking as much water as wished. Short stops when tired. For energy small sesame biscuits can be used and are best energizer. During bike ride body begins using fat to transform into power only when it finds insufficient carbs in stomach. So eating chocolate bars is not beneficial for losing fat. Remember that after 6 hr ride when you weigh your self most of wt deduction is due to dehydration and fat is lost such rides be continued for some weeks then you will notice your fat belly is getting flat and bending down becomes much easier. 
If for your hypertension you take medications like diuretics that cause dehydration you need enough water to drink while riding. Additionally, due to sweating you lose bodily salt and hence you need to add 1.5gr table salt to each liter water you drink during cycling otherwise you can get leg muscles cramps causing you unable to pedal after few hours. After ride you can take potassium supplements with food in order to keep your K/Na ratio at normal levels.
After 2 weeks steady cycling not only you notice losing fat but will be surprised that your blood pressure also normalized. Consequently, during rides if you feel lightheaded then ask your doctor to reduce/adjust your HTN medication doses so your BP does not drop too low while cycling.